# Can I Use Boostrap Sass with Ruby 1.9?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

The Bootstrap Sass gem itself will work with Ruby 1.9, but one of its dependencies is Autoprefixer-rails, which requires Ruby 2.0. Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 3):

At one point the Bootstrap Sass gem worked with Ruby 1.9, including dependencies, so we can at least go back to that version.

Digging into the Bootstrap Sass dependencies, it looks like the current gem requires only autoprefixer 5.x.

```
# from bootstrap-sass gemspec
s.add_runtime_dependency 'autoprefixer-rails', '>= 5.2.1'
```

Turns out autoprefixer moved to Ruby 2.0 at [version 6.1](https://github.com/ai/autoprefixer-rails/commit/e18e868237fa2e6bb9390c519ef93fdbea354312).

So it looks like all you need to do it set a version interval in your gemfile for autoprefixer-rails.

```
# gemfile
gem 'autoprefixer-rails', ">= 5.2.1", "< 6.1"
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '>= 3.3.6'
```